# Asynchronous webserver and garbage collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, garbage-collection, async-await

After reading Stephen Cleary's [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) on async and asp.net,  it is quite clear that using Async in web application is a big win on scalability (primarily due to non-blocking threads that are free to serve up more requests).

Although I am a little confused as to how does the Task object returned by the async operation remain in scope in an Aysnc WebServer implementation (lets say iis or self-hosted WebApi)
and not get collected.

for example,

If we have the following method in a low level Webserver implementation,

```
// some method that handles HttpListeners BeginContextAsync callback, 
public void SomeHttpListenerCallback(HttpListenerContext context)
{

    // Immediately set up the next begin context            

    // then handle the request
    // forgive me if this is incorrect but this is my understanding of how an async request would be handled
    // please feel free to point out the flaws
    var task  = messageHanlder1.SendAsync(context.Request, null); 
    task.ContinueWith(t => SendResponse(t));

}

public class MessageHandler1 : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Process request");
        // Call the inner handler.
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        Debug.WriteLine("Process response");
        return response;
    }
}
```

`SendResponse` being some method that sends the response to clients socket.

As you might have noticed, task object drops out of scope in `SomeHttpListenerCallback`, since no other thread (theoretically) has any reference to the task object, wouldnt it be marked for collection in next GC cycle?

I have read Jeffrey Ritcher's explanation (Clr via C#) of how compiler converts an aysnc method into a method with a state machine, however I fail to understand what happens to the task object if no thread waits on it.

And if a thread waits on it, wouldnt we have 1 blocked thread per request?
Any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This was pretty much my strongest hypothesis. All async operation at the very end are calls to IO and once a request has been queued in IRP, system will need the Task object to start the callback chain. By virtue of Task object being alive, all its callback objects are alive. However, I punched a hole in my own theory when I realized that not all async methods are IO bound (at bottom they are). However (punching hole in rebuttal), I noticed that the state machine is started before the task is returned. I believe this establishes the chain that keeps all these callbacks in scope. Am I right?

Comment: That link is severely broken, please add it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every async operation that you do there is some "native" operation behind it - a socket read or a file IO and such. These are native CLR operations or PInvoke calls. When starting such an operation the framework registers a callback to be called on completion. This callback is being used to complete tasks. That callback is being kept alive by "the system". For example when you say `myFileStream.BeginRead(myCallback)` then the callback *will* be called even if it is otherwise unreferenced.

Speaking in a simplified way the native operation itself keeps everything alive that must be worked on when completion happens.

This is not a hard rule but an IO framework would be pretty useless if it called your callback only sometimes.

There is nothing that prevents *any* `Task` from being collected. For example `var dummy = new TaskCompletionSource<object>().Task;` is eligible for collection immediately.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have a `Task` and nothing references it then it will be collected by the `GC`.

However, that's almost never the case. There are 2 types of tasks, Promise tasks and Delegate tasks.

Promise tasks (asynchronous) are mostly created by `TaskCompletionSource` or the compiler for an `async` method. In both cases someone holds a reference to the task so it will be able to complete it.

Delegate tasks (synchronous) however are referenced by the thread executing the delegate in them.

In your case `task` is referenced by the state machine behind `SendAsync` until it completes while `task` is referencing the continuation `Task`. When it completes the continuation is scheduled and so is referenced by the `TaskScheduler` and the thread executing `SendResponse`. When the operation completes the task will no longer be referenced and could be eventually `GC`ed.

---

You can see an example in the [implementation of `Task.Delay`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5853) where the `Task` (actually `DelayPromise` which inherits from `Task`) is being referenced by the `System.Threading.Timer` used to complete the `Task`.

Because some arguments don't actually need a timer you can see a distinction in memory usage between this:

```
static void Main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Task.Delay(int.MaxValue);
    }
}
```

And this:

```
static void Main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Task.Delay(-1); // No Timer as the delay is infinite.
    }
}
```